# PDFRenderer unable to display a file

Tags: android, pdfrenderer

I'm using API Level 21 and I'm trying to display a PDF downloaded from internet and stored in the cache directory.

```
   private void openRenderer(Context context) throws IOException {
    Log.d("NoiPA", "Opening PDF File: " + pdfPath);
    // In this sample, we read a PDF from the assets directory.
    mFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File(pdfPath),ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    //mFileDescriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(pdfPath).getParcelFileDescriptor();
    // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
    mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(mFileDescriptor);
}
```

The code above makes the app crash with the following stack trace:

```
Download: Completed -> Showing PDF
onAttach -> pdfPath: /data/data/com.vitobellini.noipa/cache/MAG 2016.pdf
Opening PDF File: /data/data/com.vitobellini.noipa/cache/MAG 2016.pdf
java.io.IOException: not create document. Error:
     at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.nativeCreate(Native Method)
     at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.<init>(PdfRenderer.java:149)
     at com.vitobellini.noipa.PdfRendererFragment.openRenderer(PdfRendererFragment.java:151)
     at com.vitobellini.noipa.PdfRendererFragment.onAttach(PdfRendererFragment.java:115)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1019)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:779)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:819)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:660)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I cannot explain to myself why that code is not working, anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience it has to do with file that you are passing to the PdfRenderer.
If you are able to open that same file with other app/library from exactly same directory that you are saving that means you should be able to open it with PdfRenderer.

Official issue here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic/issues/1 was closed, and original reporter hasn't reopened it.

Can you try exactly same sample with your own PDF file? If it doesn't work, than there is a bug with library, and I would suggest you to reopen that issue with file that doesn't work. Also feel free to try other files with your solution(very simple files).